# Google Sheets Query Extract Value by Max Spend

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-query

I'm running a Google Sheets report on our Facebook marketing campaigns and I want to use a query to return the best performing ads in each campaign by spend. The data is set up as follows:

```
Campaign Name          Ad Name          Link          Spend
Campaign 1             Ad 1             www.a.com/1   250
Campaign 1             Ad 2             www.a.com/2   100
Campaign 1             Ad 3             www.a.com/3   150
Campaign 2             Ad 1             www.a.com/4   75
Campaign 2             Ad 2             www.a.com/5   180
Campaign 3             Ad 1             www.a.com/6   300
Campaign 3             Ad 2             www.a.com/7   50
```

So what I would like is to pull out the top performing ad (the one with the largest spend) in each campaign with its corresponding link. Essentially a list that looks like:

```
Campaign Name          Ad Name          Link          Spend
Campaign 1             Ad 1             www.a.com/1   250
Campaign 2             Ad 2             www.a.com/5   180
Campaign 3             Ad 1             www.a.com/6   300
```

I am sure that I can do this using a query but just haven't been able to make the arguments work.

I can provide an example spreadsheet if needed.

Thanks a lot
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query can't handle max value by selective fields only.

Please try:

`=ArrayFormula(vlookup(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),SORT(A2:D,4,0),{1,2,3,4},))`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much – this works perfectly. 

Out of interest, is there a way to combine this with an Index/Match to pull out the second top value as well (or one formula to pull out first and second)? Or is that just getting overly complicated?

Comment: overly complicated. My formula uses sort and matches only 1 top value. If you want to pull out the second top, you need to change logic: this formula wont work.